# WSO2 DAS 3.1.0 Dashboard intergadget communication

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am trying to do intergadget communication between two gadgets, a date range picker and an batch record line trending.

The information I found is from other products from WSO2, not for DAS 3.1.0

Is it posible to do intergadget communication between a date range and a batch record line trending?

If so, does someone have an example working of this?

Its very important for our company to know this answers, because we are trying to use the WSO2 products, but we can't if we aren't able to show the historic data in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add pub-sub connection between the gadgets.
You can get the information related to inter-gadget communication on below links.

https://medium.com/@megala.11/how-to-visualize-wso2-apim-statistics-in-das-c349b3fd83a

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DS200/Configuring+Gadgets+for+Inter-gadget+Communication

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DS200/Inter-gadget+Communication